# Convert string to current float language in configuration?

Tags: localization, odoo, typeconverter

how to convert string to float using locale language fr_FR in configuration
for example:

```
my_str = '546 587,44'
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a function:

```
    def get_float(value):
        if not value: return None
        lang=self.env['res.lang'].search([('code','=',env.context.get('lang'))])
        return float(value.replace(lang.thousands_sep, '')
                              .replace(lang.decimal_point, '.'))
```

then just use it as

```
get_float(str)
```